# Transfer learning with small shapes?

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification

I want to create a model which can classify these images
[image: Images to classify]

X_train shape is **(7230, 21, 21)** having arrays of 21x21 as input.

I thought of using pre-trained model (transfer-learning), but these image arrays are of **size 21x21** and in every model in transfer-learning there is requirement for bigger image (around 224x224).

I tried to classify it using this sequential model

```
model = Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu',input_shape = (21,21,1)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation= 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(9,activation='softmax')
])
```

But this model is not working. Any solutions?

Comment: The architecture of the model should be fine. As you've stated, "this model is not working", what are the problems you're facing? Elaborate the question with the error messages and other necessary logs.

Comment: It was showing loss Nan and accuracy 0 in all epochs then I tried it using Random Forest Classifier and it is working fine.